# Spring data solr doesn't return autogenerated id after save

Tags: java, spring-boot, solr, spring-data, spring-data-solr

I'm trying simply to save entity into solr using spring data and get its autogenerated id. I see that id is generated but it was not returned back to me. Code is trivial

***entity:***

```
@SolrDocument(solrCoreName = "bank")
@Canonical
class Shop {
    @Id
    @Field
    String id
    @Field
    String name
}
```

***repository:***

```
@Repository
interface ShopRepository extends SolrCrudRepository<Shop, String>{
}
```

***handler:***

```
  @Autowired
    ShopRepository repository

    void save() {
        Shop shop = new Shop()
        shop.name = 'shop1'
        log.info("before {}", shop)
        Shop savedShop = repository.save(shop)
        log.info("after {}", savedShop)
    }
```

***dependencies:***

```
dependencies {
    compile lib.groovy_all
    compile 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-solr:1.5.10.RELEASE'
}
```

***and result is:***

```
before com.entity.Shop(null, shop1)
after com.entity.Shop(null, shop1)
```

however via solr's admin console I see  generated id:

```
{   "responseHeader":{
    "status":0,
    "QTime":0,
    "params":{
      "q":"*:*",
      "_":"1527472154657"}},   "response":{"numFound":3,"start":0,"docs":[
      {
        "name":["shop1"],
        "id":"4db1eb1d-718b-4a38-b960-6d52f9b6240c",
        "_version_":1601670593291223040,
        "name_str":["shop1"]},
      {
        "name":["shop1"],
        "id":"6ad52214-0f23-498d-82b8-82f360ef22f1",
        "_version_":1601670855078707200,
        "name_str":["shop1"]},
      {
        "name":["shop1"],
        "id":"b45b5773-f2b9-4474-b177-92c98810978b",
        "_version_":1601670887722975232,
        "name_str":["shop1"]}]   }}
```

and repository.findAll() also returns correct result with mapped id. Is it a feature or bug?

Comment: I believe it has got something to do with ID generation strategy. Try using `@GeneratedValue`

Comment: unfortunately spring-data-solr know nothing about annotation GeneratedValue

Comment: Check the definition of repository.save method, whether it returns generated id or not. If not, try to use any other method which return id after insert.

Answer (score 0):

The flow is working as expected (no ID available in the returned object):

During the Save operation

- Original object is converted in something can be digested by Solr (id is null)
- The update request (with the object with null id) is sent to Solr
- Solr process the "create" and generate (internally) the ID
- Solr response is OK/KO (with few other data...but no ID here)

So...the final object is exactly the same of the original object (id null).

A quick "workaround" can be implemented as:

```
@Repository
public interface PlaceRepo extends SolrCrudRepository<PlaceModel, String> {

    default PlaceModel create(PlaceModel model, Duration commit) {
        model.setId(IDGenerator.generateID());
        return this.save(model, commit);
    }

    default PlaceModel create(PlaceModel model) {
        return this.create(model, Duration.ZERO);
    }

}
```

You are moving the ID generation logic to the Java layer.
The Id can be generated as

```
public static String generateID() {
        return UUID.randomUUID().toString();
    }
```